# dbt : run_query macro

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dbt

When I use run_query macro on my dbt model got the following error :

> Compilation Error in model jira_custops (models/jira_custops.sql)
> 'None' has no attribute 'table'. This can happen when calling a macro that does not exist. Check for typos and/or install package dependencies with "dbt deps".

Due to this line :

```
{% set dynamic_columns = run_query(dynamic_sql_query).rows[0].sql_columns %}
```